# Rails undefined method `[]' for 2011-03-16 18:58:00 UTC:Time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, string

Total newbie with ruby and rails...and perhaps I'm making more work for myself...but unable to change the timezone to local I decided to parse the date and time and use it for my own purposes.  Except the substring is not working out for me.

```
<% ds = thejob.datestamp 
       dsyy = ds[0,4]
       dsmm = ds[5,2]   
       dsdd = ds[8,2]   
       dshrs = ds[11,2]   
       dsmin = ds[14,2]   
       dssec = ds[17,2]   
       dstz = ds[20,2] %>
```

Results in error:

```
undefined method `[]' for 2011-03-16 18:58:00 UTC:Time
```

Comment: Have you set the local timezone in config/application.rb?

Comment: NICE!  That's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure `datestamp` is actually a string, rather than a `Time` type value?

Judging by the [Ruby date/time documentation](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_date_time.htm), you may just need:

```
local = thejob.datestamp.getlocal
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ds = thejob.datestamp 
dsyy = ds.year
dsmm = ds.month   
dsdd = ds.day  
dshrs = ds.hour
dsmin = ds.min
dssec = ds.sec  
dstz = I don't remember
```

Comment: Thank you...I ended up using .strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")